# How to set up Amazon MQ RabbitMQ Cluster using Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-route53, amazon-mq

I am trying to create a RabbitMQ instance of Amazon MQ and give it a Route53 addressable name. The problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to do that since the IP addresses that would be required for an NLB are not available from the console, and the NLB that is created, seems to be nonexistent in my account. With the ActiveMQ version, there are IP Addresses in the console you can use, and there is an excellent tutorial on how to do this (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-static-custom-domain-endpoints-with-amazon-mq/), but because IPs don't show up on RabbitMQ instances, I need to find another solution.

Anyone have thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: "the NLB that is created, seems to be nonexistent in my account" what are you talking about here? Amazon doesn't automatically create an NLB with an MQ cluster. That solution you linked to walks you through manually creating an MQ cluster, then manually creating an NLB. If you manually create an NLB, then an NLB will exist in your account...

Comment: if you are using Terraform, you can do it. If manually, issue a `nslookup` to the endpoint and you should get the IP address.